# jQuery: Event CSS

Tags: html, css, dom, jquery

Please check this page first http://balipremiermanagement.com/

in that page, there is a slide show and a Logo at Top Left Corner. how to make `jQuery Event` when if the `images/101130/logo_big.jpg` Element CSS `display:block` then the logo (at top left corner) element CSS will change to `display:none`

or more simple, what i want to achieve is, when the slide show, show the Logo. the the logo at top left corner will dissapear.

How to do that with jQuery?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is relevant any longer as the website seems to have changed, but...

Apply .hide() to the element, or for an animation, 
.hide( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )

See the  [jQuery Documentation for Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for details.